# Updating specific fields in reactJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, typescript

I've three input fields, and whenever I want to update just specific field(S) rather than all of them, the ones that I didn't modify will return empty string ('') in my mysql database. So my problem is to give my users the ability to modify only the fields they need without messing up untouched fields. The current default values are the current values in database as well. I once was able to modify the targeted fields, but I couldn't have entered more than one character. This is the reason why I'm using defaultValue attributes. If anyone can help me, I would more than happy.
The sample code looks as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtOfq.png)

> I've a user interface that looks like this:

```
  interface User {
    fullName: string,
    email: string,
    password: string
  }
```

And form that looks like this:

```
     <form method="put" className="updating_current_user" onSubmit={this.updateCuurentUser.bind(this, userId)}>
                <input type="hidden" value={userId}/>
                <input
                type="text"
                defaultValue={fullName}
                onChange={(e: any) => this.setState({ user: { ...user, fullName: e.target.value } })}
                required
               />
              <input
                type="email"
                defaultValue={email}
                onChange={(e: any) => this.setState(
                  { user: { ...user, email: e.target.value } })}
                />
              <input
                type="password"
                defaultValue={password}
                onChange={(e: any) => this.setState({ user: { ...user, password: e.target.value } })}
                required
              />
            </form>
```

my express backend this way for PUT method:

```
app.put('/users/edit', (req, res) => {
    const { fullName, email, password, userId} = req.query

    const updateCurrentUser = `update users set fullName = '${fullName}', email = '${email}', password = '${password}' where userId = ${userId}`

    con.query(updateCurrentUser, (err, results) =>{
        if(err){
             res.redirect('/users')
        } else{
            res.send("Data updated...")
        }
    })
});
```

My mysql database looks:

```
create table if not exists users(
    userId INT NOT NULL auto_increment,  
    fullName VARCHAR(55), 
    email VARCHAR(55),
    password VARCHAR(55),
    PRIMARY KEY(userId)
);
```

I'm not actually using onSubmit function from the form. I'm a button click with a regular function with userId as the only parameter in order to update the database. I did do the exact same thing with POST and I didn't have any issue. So This is what my submission function looks like:

```
  editUserInfo = (userId:number) => {
    const { user } = this.state
  
   fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/edit?fullName=${user.fullName}&email=${user.email}&password=${user.password}&userId=${userId}`, {
        method: 'put',
      })
        .then(res => res.json()) 
         //this.getusers() to get all currently saved users in database
        .then(this.getUsers)
  }
```

I think that's enough or should I be much clearer!!!

Comment: Please post the full, relevant code, not pictures of code

Comment: I just did @Jayce444

Comment: Can't necessarily see anything wrong here, but can you post the full state of the form and how you're posting from the front end? I can see you're spreading the whole user object when they type, but not copying over anything else on the first level of the state object

Comment: I used the same endpoint in PostMan and was able to update everything: `http://localhost:4000/users/edit?fullName=${user.fullName}&email=${user.email}&password=${user.password}&userId=${userId}`

Comment: The whole "current" value vs. user object in your state I think may be where you're going wrong. Cos if you load up the page, type in a new username, then submit it, the email and password are initially empty strings in React, so empty values will get posted to the backend. I don't think you should duplicate them. And you also don't show how you load in the user's initial values for those fields, I assume you're doing that on mount?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your database query string will update the unmodified fields to be empty strings, regardless of which fields have values? Perhaps you should conditionally build the query based on which fields have actually been entered by the user:

```
app.put('/users/edit', (req, res) => {
    const { fullName, email, password, userId} = req.query

    // generate an array of {key, value} objects
    const mappedFields = [fullName, email, password, userId]
        .map((ea, i) => ({value: ea, key: ["fullName", "email", "password", "userId"][i]}));

    // this will be our query string
    let updateCurrentUser = '';

    // flag to track if we need to add comma to query string
    let multipleFieldsFlag = false;
    for(let ea in mappedFields) {
        if(ea.value) {
            if (!updateCurrentUser) {updateCurrentUser = 'update users set';}

            updateCurrentUser += multipleFieldsFlag ? ',' : '';
            updateCurrentUser += ` ${ea.key} = ${ea.value}`;

            multipleFieldsFlag = true;
        }
    }

    con.query(updateCurrentUser, (err, results) =>{
        if(err){
             res.redirect('/users')
        } else{
            res.send("Data updated...")
        }
    })
});
```

This has the downside that users cannot ever intentionally set a field to an empty string (because it will be skipped in updating the fields). That may or may not be an issue for you, but if it is, this should at least get you started and you can start to think about how to handle that particular edge case, perhaps by sending an explicit `null` form field value from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a better approach, I believe. I had to use two class Components where one will behave as Parent class and sends data to the other component considered here as Child component, then after all the user modifications are done, all the data, even the untouched ones, will be directly saved to the `backend` and update even the `FrontEnd`. In the parent class, I used `ComponentDidUpdate` and `ComponentDidMount` immediately one after another. So now even the page is loaded, all my expectations are being met accordingly. The problem was having multiple inputs fields with the same value names in the same component. The method I USED to create new items had exactly the same value names as the ones I used in the method that should update existing items; so, every time I was trying to update existing data, the app was triggering the fields with the method that create new data, which made it impossible to update anything unless I had to use defaultValue attributes, and it turns out default value was returning empty value if the field was submitted with being untouched. Those are my assumptions after my debugging process. I was about to use react `Context`, but it works already, so, maybe later.

```
interface UserState{
  currentUserInfo: any,
  users:Array<any>,
  user: {
    fullName: string,
    email: string
    password: string,
    userId: number
  },
}
//considers to be parent class
export default class UserTimeline extends Component<{}, UserState>{
  constructor(props: UserState){
    super(props)
    this.state = { 
      users:[],
      currentUserInfo: {},
      user: {
        fullName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
        userId: 0
      }
     } 
  }

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.updateUserInfo()
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.updateUserInfo()
  }

  updateUserInfo = () => {
    return this.state.user
  }

  
 
  //A method that will update existing data
  editCurrentUsers({ fullName, email, password, userId }: any) {
    return (
      <li key={userId}>
            <EditCurrent
              currentUserInfo={{fullName, email, password, userId}}
            />
      </li>
    )
  }

 //will return these fields from users arrays
  renderCurrentUsers({ fullName, email, password, userId }: any) {   
    return (
      <li key={userId}>
        
      </li>
    )
  }

  render() {
    const { user, users } = this.state
    
    return (
      <Router>
        {/**/}
        </Router>
    );
  }
}






interface AllCurrentUser {
  currentUserInfo: any,
}

interface SingleCurrentUser{
    currentFullName: any,
    currentEmail: string,
  currentPassword: string,
  currentUserId: number
 }


//considers to be child class Component
class EditCurrent extends Component<AllCurrentUser, SingleCurrentUser>{
  constructor(props:any){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        currentFullName: this.props.currentUserInfo.fullName,
        currentEmail: this.props.currentUserInfo.email,
        currentPassword: this.props.currentUserInfo.password,
        currentUserId: this.props.currentUserInfo.userId
    }
    this.updateFullName = this.updateFullName.bind(this);
    this.updateEmail = this.updateEmail.bind(this);
    this.updatePassword = this.updatePassword.bind(this);
    this.userDataGotUpdated = this.userDataGotUpdated.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.userDataGotUpdated()
  }

  userDataGotUpdated = () => {
    const { currentFullName, currentEmail, currentPassword, currentUserId } = this.state

    fetch(`http://localhost:4000/users/edit?fullName=${currentFullName}&email=${currentEmail}&password=${currentPassword}&userId=${currentUserId}`, {
      method: 'put',
    })
      .then(res => res.json()) 
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  }
  
  updateFullName(event:any) {   
     this.setState({
       currentFullName: event.target.value,
     }); 
  }

  updateEmail(event:any) {   
     this.setState({
       currentEmail: event.target.value,
     }); 
  }
  
  updatePassword(event:any) {   
     this.setState({
       currentPassword: event.target.value
     }); 
  }

  render() {
    const { currentFullName, currentEmail, currentPassword, currentUserId } = this.state
    
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="hidden" value={currentUserId}  /> <br />
        <input type="text" value={currentFullName} onChange={this.updateFullName} /> <br />
        <input type="email" value={currentEmail} onChange={this.updateEmail} /> <br />
        <input type="password" value={currentPassword}
          onChange={this.updatePassword}
        /> <br />
        <button onClick={this.userDataGotUpdated}>
          <Link to="/users">Update</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It's done, finally!!